# Add data dynamically to an Array

Tags: php

I want to add data to an array dynamically. How can I do that? Example

```
$arr1 = [
    'aaa',
    'bbb',
    'ccc',
];
// How can I now add another value?

$arr2 = [
    'A' => 'aaa',
    'B' => 'bbb',
    'C' => 'ccc',
];
// How can I now add a D?
```

Comment: Hey look, there is a PHP array documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (first hit when searching for `php array`)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to work with dynamic arrays in PHP.
Initialise an array:

```
$array = array();
```

Add to an array:

```
$array[] = "item"; // for your $arr1 
$array[$key] = "item"; // for your $arr2
array_push($array, "item", "another item");
```

Remove from an array:

```
$item = array_pop($array);
$item = array_shift($array);
unset($array[$key]);
```

There are plenty more ways, these are just some examples.

Comment: I just want to add something. array_push function should only be used for big arrays as described in the description. Always prefer $array[] = "new item" for small insertions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: just to add to your very good answer, `$array = [];` is also an option for array initialisation

Answer (score 13):

```
$array[] = 'Hi';
```

pushes on top of the array.

```
$array['Hi'] = 'FooBar';
```

sets a specific index.

Answer (score 10):

Let's say you have defined an empty array:

```
$myArr = array();
```

If you want to simply add an element, e.g. 'New Element to Array', write

```
$myArr[] = 'New Element to Array';
```

if you are calling the data from the database, below code will work fine

```
$sql = "SELECT $element FROM $table";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)//if it finds any row
{
   while($result = mysql_fetch_object($query))
   {
      //adding data to the array
      $myArr[] = $result->$element;
   }
}
```

Comment: From where do you see $element and $table values are **SELECT**ed ?

Answer (score 6):

You should use method array_push to add value or array to array exists

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);

/** GENERATED OUTPUT
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this?:

```
$array[] = 'newItem';
```

Answer (score 3):

In additon to directly accessing the array, there is also

[`array_push`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) — Push one or more elements onto the end of array

Answer (score 2):

```
$dynamicarray = array();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $dynamicarray[$i]=$i;
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding array elements dynamically to an Array And adding new element
>   to an Array

```
$samplearr=array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($rslt as $row) {
        $arr['feeds'][$count]['feed_id'] = $row->feed_id;
        $arr['feeds'][$count]['feed_title'] = $row->feed_title;
        $arr['feeds'][$count]['feed_url'] = $row->feed_url;
        $arr['feeds'][$count]['cat_name'] = $this->get_catlist_details($row->feed_id);
        foreach ($newelt as $cat) {
            array_push($samplearr, $cat);              
        }
        ++$count;
}
$arr['categories'] = array_unique($samplearr); //,SORT_STRING

$response = array("status"=>"success","response"=>"Categories exists","result"=>$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun...

```
$array_a = array('0'=>'foo', '1'=>'bar');
$array_b = array('foo'=>'0', 'bar'=>'1');

$array_c = array_merge($array_a,$array_b);

$i = 0; $j = 0;
foreach ($array_c as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {$array_d[$i] = $value; $i++;}
    if (is_numeric($value)) {$array_e[$j] = $key; $j++;}
}

print_r($array_d);
print_r($array_e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way I think

```
       $newArray = array();

for($count == 0;$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getResults);$count++)
    {
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    { 
    $newArray[$count]{$key} = $row[$key];
    }
}
```