# how to get single result from nested foreach

Tags: php

I have a problem I've been trying to solve for two weeks now, please I need help on this. I do not understand using array well so please bear with me.

I'm trying to combine two arrays and store them in one array so I did this.

```
$oldvalue =$_SESSION[oldmids]; //value example aa=1,bb=2,cc=3;
$newvalue =$_SESSION[newmids]; //value example 001,002,003;


$result =array();
foreach($oldvalue as $oldval){

$kk =explode('=',$oldval);//i want to keep my tagging so
$oldtag =$kk[0];         // I use explode.

    foreach($newvalue as $newid){
        $kk =$oldtag.$newid;
        $result[] =$kk;
    }   
}   

//  print_r($result);
```

my goal here is to keep my old tag and replace with numeric value, I don't have a problem with
the output, but I only need to get a unique value from my array $result. I tried using array_unique, but failed. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Access it like `$_SESSION['oldmids']` instead of `$_SESSION[oldmids]`

Comment: Show us how you tried to use `array_unique`, because that should be a good approach.

Comment: http://www.php.net/array_push go through the link this will be helpful. use `array_push`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325009/add-data-dynamically-to-an-array
session is used like this `$_SESSION['keyword']` you're doing in wrong way.

Comment: thank you for all your suggestions at least I can check other options. 
I tried adding single quote as suggested, but to no avail.

I used array unique outside my foreach loop.
$result2 =array_unique($result);
print_r($result2);
but I still got the same duplicate result.

I checked the link and I noticed the array_push. unfortunately
for a newbie this is quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I think that array_push() is what you want:
http://www.php.net/array_push

This is my best guess:

```
$oldvalue =$_SESSION[oldmids]; //value example aa=1,bb=2,cc=3;
$newvalue =$_SESSION[newmids]; //value example 001,002,003;


$result = array();
foreach($oldvalue as $oldval){

$kk =explode('=',$oldval);//i want to keep my tagging so
$oldtag =$kk[0];         // i use explode.

    foreach($newvalue as $newid){
        $kk =$oldtag.$newid;
        array_push($result, $kk);
    }   
}   

print_r($result);
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I tried the code above and it works, unfortunately not what I expected and not quite there yet. I look further on this. :)