# Populate multidimensional array with data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

While renown scientists are looking into other dimensions I'm trying to figure out how to populate multidimensional arrays with dynamic data.

I need to add an undetermined number of values that are calculated from a random function.

```
function my_random ($min, $max) {

        $random_var = rand($min, $max);
        return $random_var;
    }
```

I would like my array to look like this:

```
$array_example = [
                'id' => $id, 
                'value1' => $value1,
                'value2' => $value2

            ];
```

...or maybe like this:

```
$array[$i] = [
                'id' => $id, array(
                    'value1' => $value1,
                    'value2' => $value2
                )   
        ];
```

I figured a simple for-loop would do the trick and so I tried this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {

    $array[$i] = $i;
    $array[$i] = [
            'id' => $i, array(
                'value1' => $value1,
                'value2' => $value2
            )
        ];
}
```

...but it comes out all wrong (from console):

`string(103) "{"id":2,"value1":[14,{"1":{"id":1,"0":{"value1":[14],"value2":[11]}}},13],"value2":[11,19]}"`

The for-loop seems to nest them. I tried different functions, hoping to get it right: range() to get the id and then populate it with data, array_push() and I even tried to combine and merge.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325009/add-data-dynamically-to-an-array) makes it look simple:

```
$array[] = "item";
$array[$key] = "item";
array_push($array, "item", "another item");
```

But this solution will only work to create the index.

How do I insert those values into each index dynamically? What I ultimately need is to be able to access the array and its values like this:

```
$array[0]["value1"].
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what exact output you want. There are two expected outputs. And the code will produce another different array. Be specific. Also what is the purpose of `my_random` function? You are not using it anywhere .

Comment: I am using it in my code, I just didn't insert it here. The reason I mentioned the random function is to show why I need to iterate with the for-loop while adding the date from the random function. So for each index (0, 1, 2), there's going to be a random value that needs to be inserted to each of those indexes.

Comment: To receive a quality answer, you need to post a quality question.  Show us what your input array looks like.  Do you want random elements, random number of elements, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Indexed array of associative arrays

> An [array in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

The following function takes one optional integer argument, or [defaults to `10`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-138), and initiates a [`for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) to create an [indexed `Array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-59) of [associative `array()`s](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>
<?php 
    function createArrayOf( $quantity = 10 ) {
        $arr = [];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $quantity; ++$i ) {
            $arr[ $i ] = array( 
                "value_1" => "some value",
                "value_2" => "another value"
            );
        }
        return $arr;
    }
?>
<pre><?php var_export( createArrayOf( 5 ) ); ?></pre>
</body></html>
```

Output using [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) which:

> gets structured information about the given variable. It is similar to [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) with one exception: the returned representation is valid PHP code.

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'value_1' => 'some value',
        'value_2' => 'another value',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'value_1' => 'some value',
        'value_2' => 'another value',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'value_1' => 'some value',
        'value_2' => 'another value',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
        'value_1' => 'some value',
        'value_2' => 'another value',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
        'value_1' => 'some value',
        'value_2' => 'another value',
    ),
)
```

Comment: It's that simple when you know the syntax. :) Thanks!

Comment: @DanSebastian - NP; YW. Thanks for accepting. I have added those extra details I promised. Happy coding!